# NullPointerException Error when printing Listnode val after reversing linkedlist

Tags: java, data-structures, nullpointerexception

You can see the problem in the attached picture. I also tried the print statement, "System.out.println(palindrome.val);" and I'm getting the same error. Please help me fix this. Thanks

[click here to see the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPpmU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the `reverse` function you are looping while `head` is not equals to `null`. After the loop you are returning `head`, which will definitely be null when the loop breaks.

So `palindrome` is `null` every time. And so doing `palindrome.val` gives `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this you can simple return the `prev` node from the reverse function.